# Monitor a log file for new logs

Tags: .net, file-io

I'd like to implement a simple program to monitor log files, to create a dynamic summary of events that are occurring. Implementing the aggregation of events is fairly simple, but I'm wonder what would be the best way to read the log file.

I'd like to be able to open the file and then receive an event with the new data when it is added to the file. I was wondering if something like this was already in the BCL or as an open source project? It feels like it should but I can't find anything that exactly fits the bill :)

It would be fairly simple to implement something like this with the FileSystemWatcher, but if I've understood the docs correctly FileSystemWatcher only notifies you that a file has changed, it does not give you the data written to file. Admittedly once you know a file has changed, it wouldn't be too hard to read the new data, but I'm looking to avoid reinventing the wheel here.

Many thanks,
Robert